# Сортировка списка словарей с парсингом

Tags: python-3.x

**Дано**: словарь со списком словарей

```
 {'id': 1,
 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': [{'itemid': '138451',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[foo1]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for foo1',
             'prevvalue': '0'},
            {'itemid': '97404',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[bar2]',
             'lastvalue': '8',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bar2',
             'prevvalue': '8'},
            {'itemid': '97412',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[baz3]',
             'lastvalue': '2',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for baz3',
             'prevvalue': '2'},
            {'itemid': '144281',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[#wtf]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for #wtf',
             'prevvalue': '0'}]}
```

**Требуется**: Найти средне арифметическое (average) между `prevvalue` и `lastvalue` , добавить в эти словари новый ключ `avg` с этим значением, отсортировать по `avg` и вывести первые 10 `key_` в формате `bar2,baz3,foo1,#wtf` (без пробелов, просто строка)

**Что я для этого делаю**:

```
metrics = {'id': 1,
 'jsonrpc': '2.0',
 'result': [{'itemid': '138451',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[foo1]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for foo1',
             'prevvalue': '0'},
            {'itemid': '97404',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[bar2]',
             'lastvalue': '8',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bar2',
             'prevvalue': '8'},
            {'itemid': '97412',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[baz3]',
             'lastvalue': '2',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for bz3',
             'prevvalue': '2'},
            {'itemid': '144281',
             'key_': 'rows_changed[#wtf]',
             'lastvalue': '0',
             'name': 'Rows changed (delta) for #wtf',
             'prevvalue': '0'}]}

for idx,val in enumerate(metrics['result']):
  metrics['result'][idx]['avg'] = (int(metrics['result'][idx]['prevvalue']) + int(metrics['result'][idx]['lastvalue'])) / 2

print(','.join(metrics['result'][idx]['key_'] for idx,k in enumerate(sorted(metrics['result'], key=lambda i: i['avg'], reverse=True)[:10])))
```

Но что-то тут не работает и он выводит просто первые 10 элементов по порядку, но не отсортированные. Очевидно, я что-то не понимаю.
И вопрос как избавиться от `rows_changed[]` открыт. Полагаю как-то через `re`, но может есть способ без импорта чего-либо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(','.join(metrics['result'][idx]['key_'] for idx,k in enumerate(sorted(metrics['result'], key=lambda i: i['avg'], reverse=True)[:10])))
```

Ошибка тут, вы попытались запихнуть все в одну строку, и запутались, если это разбить, то

Тут все ок - `sorted(metrics['result'], key=lambda i: i['avg'], reverse=True)`

Но далее из этого берется `for idx,k in enumerate`, и затем `k` никак не используется: `metrics['result'][idx]['key_']`
Т.е. просто бедутся значения из `metrics['result']` по порядку, т.к. `idx` это просто порядковый номер итерации, и всегда будет равен `0, 1, 2, ...`

А от `rows_changed` избавится так:

```
a = 'rows_changed[bar2]'
print(a[13:-1])  # 'bar2'
```

Comment: `rows_changed` эта штука меняется, но я выкрутился с помощью `len(tut_eta_shtuka)+1` :)